# What limitations are imposed when using Kundera on an RDBMS, versus other JPA implementations

Tags: kundera

When using a database like Cassandra, Kundera imposes limitations consistent with the underlying database.  The documentation doesn't make clear, however, whether these limitations also apply to RDBMS's used under Kundera.

In other words, does Kundera provide access to all the functionality of the underlying Hibernate implementation when working with an RDBMS?

Comment: Regarding, Kundera imposed limitations over cassandra. Could you please share few examples?  Most of JPA RDBMS functionality should work. However, i guess Hibernate specific functions may cause some issue.

Comment: @vivekmishra Thanks very much - I just meant that, AFAIK, when running over Cassandra, Kundera won't do what Cassandra cannot natively do - joins, etc.  I believe you're telling me that, on the other hand, JPQL joins should work when running Kundera over, say, PostgreSQL.

Comment: "Joins" are specific to RDBMS world. But not for nosql DBs such as Cassandra, i suppose that's why they are not there.From Kundera's perspective that's the reason joins doesn't work with Cassandra. For dealing with such requirements in big data domain, i suggest to use Hive or Map-reduce stuff.